# how to create variable in robot framework with a structure type defined in c++ header

Tags: python, robotframework

Assume c++ header file contains the following structure:

```
struct myTempSubStruct
{
    u32 v1;
    u16 v2;
    u8  v3;
};
struct myTempStruct
{
    u8 v4;
    u8 v5;
    myTempSubstruct v6;
};
```

And write a new python class which uses the c++ structure:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

class generated_messages(object):

    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'GLOBAL'

    def __init__(self):
        self.syscom = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('syscom_rammbock')

    def myStruct(self, name):
        self.syscom.new_struct('myStruct', name)
        self.myTempStruct('myTempStruct')
        self.syscom.end_struct()

    def myTempReq(self):
        return myStruct
```

Then in Robot framework, write a testscript, my purpose is to create a variable here with the c++ structure:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    generated_messages.py

*** Test Cases ***
MyCase
    Set global variable     ${msgMyTemp}    myTempReq
    Set global variable     ${msgMySub}     ${msgMyTemp.v6}
    ${msgMySub.v1}    Evaluate    1
```

But seems something wrong in my code above, there is always error like below:

> "Resolving variable '${msgMySub.v1}' failed: AttributeError: 'unicode'
>   object has no attribute"

Anyone who can help me to figure out how to improve my code?